# Xcode 10 Migration Errors

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

I am getting build errors after migrating to Xcode 10 (Multiple commands produce...). How do I resolve them?

```
     Showing All Messages
 :-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/deepaksharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-     ekrrzesacinkoeffhnglauydvxex/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.app/tint.png':
 1) Target 'MyProject' (project 'MyProject') has copy command from '/Users/deepaksharma/MyProject/MyProject/png/White Balance/tint.png' to '/Users/deepaksharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-ekrrzesacinkoeffhnglauydvxex/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.app/tint.png'
 2) Target 'MyProject' (project 'MyProject') has copy command from '/Users/deepaksharma/MyProject/MyProject/tint.png' to '/Users/deepaksharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-ekrrzesacinkoeffhnglauydvxex/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.app/tint.png'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved them by opening "Copy Bundle Resources" and looking for duplicate inclusions, and deleting duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by doing the following steps:

1.Goto file -> Workspace setting in Xcode.
[image]

2.select Legacy Build system in Build system then click done,

[image]

3. Check for your added info.plist have the correct path in targets->Build Phases->copy bundle resources. If not Delete the info.plist  and then add the info.plist again.

It will resolve the build issue with the new Xcode 10.

If you want to work with the new build system, then you can find the troubleshooting help [enter link description here](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev621201fb0)