# Multiple errors after migrating to Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

After updating to Xcode 10, I am getting the following errors in my project :

First error :

> :-1: Multiple commands produce
> '/Users/maropost/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XYZ-dorcxsyibrmjnndrycgblntogjan/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XYZ.framework/Info.plist':
>
> 1. Target 'XYZ' (project 'MPPush') has copy command from
>    '/Users/maropost/Documents/Work/iOS/Products/SDK/SwiftFromStart/XYZ/XYZ/Info.plist'
>    to
>    '/Users/maropost/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XYZ-dorcxsyibrmjnndrycgblntogjan/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XYZ.framework/Info.plist'
> 2. Target 'XYZ' (project 'XYZ') has process command with output
>    '/Users/maropost/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XYZ-dorcxsyibrmjnndrycgblntogjan/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XYZ.framework/Info.plist'

Second error :

> Could not delete
> `/Users/maropost/Documents/Work/iOS/Products/SDK/SwiftFromStart/XYZ/build`
> because it was not created by the build system and it is not a
> subfolder of derived data.

Third error :

> Command PhaseScriptExecution emitted errors but did not return a
> nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Already checked [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412351/xcode-10-migration-errors) but unrelated.

Comment: Have you tried removing info.plist from `Build phases -> copy bundle resources`

Comment: @Rugmangathan : Yup. Tried that.

Answer (score 9):

For the below error:

Could not delete /Users/maropost/Documents/Work/iOS/Products/SDK/SwiftFromStart/MPPush/build because it was not created by the build system and it is not a subfolder of derived data.

According to 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes/build_system_release_notes_for_xcode_10

The Workaround is to **Delete the build folder manually** which is in your framework's project directory. Hope this helps!

Comment: Confirmed that doing `rm -rf platforms/ios/build` and then `cordova clean` was able to complete without the "not created by the build system" error.

Comment: worked for me after upgrade to xcode 12.3 on osx catalina

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed issues by enabling `Legacy mode`. Do follow the below steps it will help you.

> `In Xcode, Goto File -> Project/Workspace settings > Advanced -> Select Legacy`

Please refer below screenshots for further assistance.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 2]

## IMPORTANT NOTE:

**CLEAN + BUILD & MAKE SURE YOUR DELETED DERIVEDATA FOLDER FROM TRASH**

Check your **Copy Bundle Resources** in `Build Phase`, You should find some files(should be images in your situation) in that list twice. Delete them and rebuild them.

Comment: This fixed **Multiple commands produce ** issue. But not all.